# How to test Bluetooth functionality using React Native

Tags: react-native, mobile, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am working on Senior Design project which is a bluetooth based application. The problem I am trying to figure out for couple of days is, how to deploy the mobile app for testing the functionality. The app operates with iBeacon. I am using classic React Native CLI.

I would appricate any advise on explanation or options to deploy the mobile application for testing. I was wondering if deploying it through XCode is a way, but it seems super inefficient and time consuming.

Comment: Are you asking how to deploy to a simulator for running automated unit tests?  Or are you asking how to deploy to do manual interactive testing?    Note that any substantive testing of the app’s use of the Bluetooth stack, you need to deploy to a physical iPhone and test interactively.  Automated testing of Bluetooth functions is difficult enough to be impractical.

Comment: I need to test it on an actual phone since I cannot test the Bluetooth functionality through the simulator. What does testing interactively means? @davidgyoung

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does the [documentation for running an app on a device](https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device) contain what you are looking for?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan I tried it in the past but it did not work well. I am reading through it again and see if I did not make a mistake back then. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is always a bit tricky and time consuming to debug Bluetooth functions on with ReactNative apps on a physical iPhone.  There are really only two options:

1. Run with an expo server (`npm start` from your project folder)
2. Run with the ReactNative code bundled with your app.  (Simply stop the Expo server used in step 1 after the first time you run your app -- but you will need to restart the expo server and re-run   each time you change your code so that it gets loaded to the iPhone app's bundle.)

Either way, you need to launch the app onto your iPhone with XCode, and you can see ReactNative debug lines in the XCode debug console.  If you are running Expo, you can see debug lines there as well.

Running with bundled code can be advantageous because sometimes you need to test when not tethered to your workstation.

Comment: Hey, I was actually able to deploy it. However, I was playing around and I was trying to use Expo instead of CLI, however, the deployment was not possible since I do not have paid Apple Developer license. Therefore, do you know if it is possible that while using Expo, you need to have the paid version but with CLI you don't? It seems weird to me and I do not understand why would it be that way..

Comment: You need to have an Apple developer account to run an app on a physical iPhone or iPad (the simulator does not require a paid account).  This has nothing to do with Expo.

Comment: The reason Apple requires a paid developer account is because they are trying to maintain control of the ability to side load apps onto iPhones.   Essentially, they are trying to stop consumers from going around the AppStore.  By requiring a paid developer account to load apps onto a physical phone, they can force you to agree to their terms of use, and they can then revoke the privilege of side loading apps as they see fit.